# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op: Getting this error message

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, apk

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Application.mk'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
}
```

> Getting error message: Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op Message{kind=ERROR,
>   text=Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op, sources=[Unknown source
>   file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: Why are you using jar for support library?

Comment: If I don't use jar, it's giving me molley.SetContentView error.

Comment: You should not use jar as you will have to do a lot work when you want to update support library version. You should solve that error instead of this. As this may work for now but increase your headaches in the long run.